How can i list root objects JavaScript
So I have several objects and classes in my script tag
const Main = {}
const App = {}
class Game {}
let state = 777

etc. I'd like to list them.
I've tried
Object.keys(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(window)).join(' ')
and
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(window).join(' ')
None of them work, but I'm able to list functions function example() {}

This sounds like an XY Problem. For what purpose do you want to list them?

You probably don't want to, but there are many similar questions on Stackoverflow Getting All Variables In Scope

Um, it's no XY problem, this is exactly what I want! To get a TOC of my old code, with forgotten names.
